# Error when running loop to section out data in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, csv, error, loop

I am attempting to run a loop in R that looks at home ranges of 27 individual animals by individual and by year.

I tried running this code:

```
df <- read_csv('animaltelemetry.csv')

df<-data.frame(df)



sapply(df, 
       class)
df$Y <- as.numeric(df$Y)
is.numeric(df$Y)

df$X<-as.numeric(df$X)
is.numeric(df$X)

sum(is.na(df$X))    # 2 NAs
sum(is.na(df$Y))

#help

#x and y are decimal coordinates. IDs are numbers, years are set up 2020,2021,or 2022.

#I can't show the location data as it is a sensitive species.

*outLoopbox<-data.frame()
i <- 27 #27 individuals
for(i in unique(df$ID)) {
  for(j in unique(df[df$ID==i,"Year"]))
    
test.kde<-kernelUD(df[df$ID==i, df$Year==j], h="href")*
```

but I keep receiving the error:

> "Error in unique.default(df[df$ID == i, "Year"]) :
> unique() applies only to vectors"

Additionally, when I section out this information. I want to bind it into a cv and then separate spatial polygons for each individual for each year.

How can I do this?

Comment: I've tried to create a data frame as alike to yours as possible from your description but I can't break `unique` on it like you have. `unique` works perfectly well on data frames, returning unique rows. Are you doing anything with `df` that you've not shown us? Can you show us your workflow but replace X and Y (and anything else) with random numbers (to avoid disclosure) and get the same errors? eg I did  `df = data.frame(X=runif(20), Y=runif(20), ID=sample(1:3, 20, TRUE), "Year"=sample(1990:1995, 20, TRUE))` and then threw in a couple of `NA` in `df$X` and `df$Y`.

Comment: Also, your problem might be more easily solved using something like `split(df, list(df$ID, df$Year), drop=FALSE)` which returns a list where each element is a data frame from unique values of Year and ID. You'd then run an `lapply` over the elements and get back a list of results.

Comment: ok so I created a new code but now the error : "Error in kernelUD(box.test_sp$geometry, h = "href") : 
  xy should inherit the class SpatialPoints"